# Error loading preview on Firebase Storage with images [Uploaded from Firebase Admin SDK]

Tags: node.js, firebase-storage, firebase-console

I am uploading images to firebase storage using the Admin SDK from NodeJS. When I try to preview the file it doesn't load because it is broken.

Its size is correct, but the preview in the dashboard just throws an error, and the image url returns a white/black small square (depends on the browser).
[image: Firebase Dashboard image preview broken]

[image: Image URL is broken]

This is my code from NodeJS:

```js
            const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
            await bufferStream.end(Buffer.from(user.photoURL, 'base64'));

            const mimeType = user.photoURL.match(/[^:]\w+\/[\w-+\d.]+(?=;|,)/)[0];
            const fileExtension = mimeType.split('/').pop();

            const file = storageBucket.file(`avatars/${user.username}.${fileExtension}`);

            const uid = v4();
            console.log(uid);
            bufferStream.pipe(file.createWriteStream({
                metadata: {
                    contentType: mimeType,
                    metadata: {
                        firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uid,
                    },
                },
            }))
                .on('error', (error) => {
                    console.log('error', error);
                })
                .on('finish', () => {
                // The file upload is complete.
                    console.log('COMPLETED, WORKED');
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it myself in the end, just for future reference:

Given the exact same code I posted in the original question, I just had to remove the text preceding the actual base64.

Original base64: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQA=

Needed base64: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQA=

Just remove the first part of the string so it looks like this:

```js
bufferStream.end(Buffer.from(user.photoURL.split(';base64,')[1], 'base64'));
```